# Take values in a tuple list and put in another list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

say I have a list of tuples. I want to put the second element of all tuples in their own list while preserving the original order. Are there any quick and dirty ways to do this?

example before sorting.

```
[(0,'apple'),
(1,'pineapple'),
(11,'cherry'),
(12,'banana'),
(13,'mango'),
(14,'boot'),
(15,'mangosteen')]
```

after sorting

```
['apple',
'pineapple',
'cherry',
'banana',
'mango',
'boot',
'mangosteen']
```

Answer (score 3):

You essentially just need to map the operation of getting the element at index 1 of each tuple in a list and produce a new list.

Given:

```
>>> LoT
[(0, 'apple'), (1, 'pineapple'), (11, 'cherry'), (12, 'banana'), (13, 'mango'), (14, 'boot'), (15, 'mangosteen')]
```

You can use a list comprehension and access the element of interest of each tuple:

```
>>> [t[1] for t in LoT]
['apple', 'pineapple', 'cherry', 'banana', 'mango', 'boot', 'mangosteen']
```

You can use tuple unpacking:

```
>>> [b for _,b in LoT]
['apple', 'pineapple', 'cherry', 'banana', 'mango', 'boot', 'mangosteen']
```

Which fails if the tuple is anything but 2 elements long.

Alternatively, you can use `zip`:

```
>>> list(zip(*LoT))[1]
('apple', 'pineapple', 'cherry', 'banana', 'mango', 'boot', 'mangosteen')
```

You can use an [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
>>> list(map(itemgetter(1),LoT))
['apple', 'pineapple', 'cherry', 'banana', 'mango', 'boot', 'mangosteen']
```

With Python3 you need to use `list` around `zip` to subscript the first element or around `map` to show it. Combined with loops or other flow contol in Python 3, you likely would not need that.

The first, `[t[1] for t in LoT]`, is the most idiomatic and the last, `map(itemgetter(1),LoT)` may be the fastest.

Comment: What is this data structure called? When I plug in "t[1] for t in LoT" my console says it is a generator type.

Comment: Put into the console *exactly* what I did and that should work. Then work backwards from there to you use case. You need to use `[...]` to get a list comprehension.

Comment: I did that and it works, I was wondering how to reference in the future. Radish says it's called "tuple unpacking"?

Comment: Suppose you have `t=(1,2)` and you want to access `2`. You can do `t[1]` to access the second element (the square bracket is either a slice or index of that tuple) or you can unpack the tuple into named values: `a,b=t` and the second element will be assigned to `b`. There are upsides and downsides to that. If your tuple is not exactly 2 element in length, `a,b=t` is an error. `[]` is an operator in Python which corresponds to the  [\__getitem\__](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) method.

Answer (score 2):

Tuple unpacking as an alternative.

```
[b for a,b in lst]
```